# Set imageview photo dynamically

Tags: android, imageview

I have +300 png pictures.Their names are like; aaa.png abka.png bxja.png daw.png.

According to my setImage(String pictureName) function i want to set imageview View resource dynamically.

```
private void setImage(String pictureName){
      myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable + picturename);
}
```

My main idea is like this but as you can see it is imposible.
What did i think to solve this problem is creating switch statemant for all +300 images but it will be really huge effort to implement this.

What am i asking is; is there a any easy way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this code, assuming that the function `setImage` is a member of activity

```
private void setImage(String pictureName)
{
     int id = getResources().getIdentifier(pictureName,"drawable",getPackageName());
     myImgView.setBackgroundResource(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.drawable + picturename` won't work because `R.drawable.picturename` is actually an integer that references your resource.

However, you can use [Resources.getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get that integer.

Then you can call `setBackgroundResource()` with the output